# How do I get all my files and lists backed up so they will open on a non-Sharepoint server?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, move

We need to move our site off Sharepoint as it is not one of the supported products(supported by my co., that is) in a security feature we must implement.
If I was moving to another sharepoint server, I know I could back up the files/lists/dbs on the current server - then restore them on the new server.
However, I'm not sure how to get a backup (create a copy) of all things on this Sharepoint server - so I can open it on another server (I only know the new server will be Windows based)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell to download all files into a Local Folder. You can export List data into an Excel File.

And use API available as part of the new server to upload it back.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://siteurl
$list = $web.Lists["ListName"]
$localfolder = "C:\Backup"

RecurseFolder($list.RootFolder.Url)
foreach ($f in $list.Folders) {
    ProcessFolder($f.Url)
}

function RecurseFolder {
    param($fUrl)
    $f = $web.GetFolder($fUrl)
    foreach ($file in $f.Files) {
        $localfolder = $localfolder + "/" + $folder.Url 
        if (!(Test-Path -path $localfolder))
        {
            New-Item $localfolder -type directory 
        }
        $binary = $file.OpenBinary()
        $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($localfolder + "/" + $file.Name), Create
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
        $writer.write($binary)
        $writer.Close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  It sounds like it would definetly work (unfortunately I don't have & cannot load the sharepoint cmdlets into Powershell - and am not allowed to run shell scripts).  I long for my UNIX days :-)

Comment: You should try using SharePoint Management Shell.